# Should there be a comma before 'just'? "If you love yourself just ignore them"

Tags: punctuation, commas

Is there a comma before 'just' in the sentence below?

> If you love yourself just ignore them because no matter how hard you try they won't understand.

Comment: It's not needed. A comma after *them* would better represent the way we would **say** the sentence.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Please correct the spelling of "comma" in your title. "comma" and "coma" are different words. Thank you.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You should be thinking about whether there's a ***pause in speech*** at that point in the spoken version (the only reason for the comma is to reflect that pause, if it exists). But you could just check out some written instances of the sequence [**if you love me**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22if+you+love+me%22) in Google Books to see how often it's followed by a comma.

Comment: No, there is no coma before just.